# Declaring mutual parameters in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring

I have mutual parameter (either/or) that need to be send to the Spring controller. But not sure how I can implement it. Right now I am defining as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/service/bookRoom")
public String bookRoom(@RequestParam(value="param1", required=false) Long param1,
                       @RequestParam(value="param2", required=false) Long param2) {
  if((param1.isEmpty() && param2.isEmpty()) ||
     (param1 && param2)) {
    return "error";
  } 

  if(param1) {
    return doSomethingWith(param1);        
  }
  if(param2) {
    return doSomethingWith(param2);
  }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean a mutual parameter?

Comment: @Mr.777 - Mutual mean I need at least one. param1 or param2 and not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the value, you could pass the parameter as a boolean.

Or you could use spring form validation [spring form validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: I do need value. Edited original post.

Comment: Then I would write a validator or just use the code in your post.